# How to use the verbs "rewind" and "fast-forward"?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

As far as I know, one can use these verbs with the preposition "to" like in "rewind/fast-forward a tape to some point".

1. How about "until"? Can it be used with these verbs?
2. If one needs to make a tape go X seconds back/forward, can he say "rewind/fast-forward a tape X seconds"?

Answer (score 1):

We can say it like this:

"Rewind / fast-forward the movie until you reach that particular frame."

The answer to your second question is yes you can.

Comment: Interesting to note that many younger people will have never seen, or used, an audio or  video machine, which had a physical tape that could be rewound.

Comment: @Michael Harvey Yes, that's interesting, I think "skipping to a particular scene" can be used with digital videos, because it can happen instantly.

Comment: How to rephrase "rewind/fast-forward X minutes" using the verb "skip"?

Comment: @Vova We can say "Skip the first 10 minutes and go straight to ......"